# sh - Delete Directory Whenever it Appears

Tags: cron, sh, resource-cleanup

In my application, whenever I open VS2013 there is an annoying folder being generated which causes my whole build to fail. The folder has some old dependencies which I do not want. I couldn't be bothered to find out why it is appearing there: I just want it gone when VS2013 starts up.

I need a simple script to delete it whenever it appears. To remove a directory we do:

```
rm -rf FolderThatWontGoAway
```

But is there way to magically tell a `sh` script to delete something when it shows up in the file system? Something like:

```
if [[ -z $(find -name "FolderThatWontGoAway") ]];
then 
    echo "Folder is not here."
else
     #remove!
     rm -rf FolderThatWontGoAway 
fi
```

**Note:** A cron would not be suitable because I open and close VS2013 too erratically to know how frequently this job should run.

Comment: I think the better answer would be to fix your build process so the existence of a directory it's not interested in doesn't terminally confuse it....

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using `inotifywait`. Something like this:

```
inotifywait -m -e create . | 
while read dir ev file
do 
    if [ -d "$file" ] && [ "$file" == "FolderThatWontGoAway" ]
    then 
        rm -rf "$file"
    fi
done
```

This will monitor the current directory for "create" events. If a new directory is created with the name "FolderThatWontGoAway", it will remove the folder and its contents.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck using Windows but after a quick Google Search I found: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx as an alternative to inotify.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that because the question had a `sh` tag, you were using some sort of Unix based system.